# How to render to template with dropdownbox in django?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, rendering, dropdown

I'm a beginner Django. And I got a problem with rendering to the template.
I have a model(models.py) which has the class "FuelInfo"; includes ForeignKey.

```
from django.db import models


class Traveler(models.Model):
    traveler_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.traveler_name

class FuelInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Traveler, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    efficiency = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Also views.py is like :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import FuelInfo

def traveler_list(request):
    travelers = FuelInfo.objects.all()
    context = {'travelers':travelers}
    return render(request, 'fuelcost/home.html', context)

def traveler_detail(request, pk):
    traveler = get_object_or_404(FuelInfo, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'fuelcost/calfuel.html', {'traveler': traveler})
```

And urls.py is :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'fuelcost'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.traveler_list, name='home'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.traveler_detail, name='calfuel'),
]
```

I want to make a dropdown that is render to template "calfuel.html" in home.html.
So I made a template("home.html") like :

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <body>

        {% if travelers %}

        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'fuelcost:calfuel' pk=traveler.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="traveler">
        {% for traveler in travelers %}
            <option value="{{ traveler.id }}">{{ traveler.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}    
        </select>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Select" />
        </form>
        
        {% else %}
        <p>No travelers are available</p>
        
        {% endif %}

    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't works and i received error.
[image: error messege]

(My urlpattern is fuelcost/.)
Actually I can go into fuelcost/1 or fuelcost/2 that is views.traveler_detail named "calfuel". But I can't go into fuelcost/ that is views.traveler_list named "home".

I don't know what I have to do more.  plz, tell me what is wrong with this.

Comment: At this line `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'fuelcost:calfuel' pk=traveler.pk %}">` there is no `traveler` in the context only `travelers` (you later loop over it). Which objects pk do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use pk of  `def traveler_detail`. First when `fuelcost/home.html` shows `def traveler_list` by for loop, and when I select a `traveler`, it goes `<int:pk>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% block content %}
<body>

    {% if travelers %}
    {% for traveler in travelers %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'fuelcost:calfuel' pk=traveler.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="traveler">
        <option value="{{ traveler.id }}">{{ traveler.name }}</option>    
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% else %}
    <p>No travelers are available</p>
    
    {% endif %}

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

you have to keep the form inside loop so that it can get pk of traveler

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I got another problem(drowdown occurs as many as pk) but I will fix it.  :) Thanks